# Не отвечает webhook бот

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, flask, telebot

```
from textwrap import dedent
from textwrap import dedent
from unittest import TestCase
from unittest.mock import patch
import wayforpay
from wayforpay import WayForPay
from wayforpay import constants
from wayforpay.api import Api
from wayforpay.constants import API_URL
from wayforpay.utils import generate_signature
from flask import Flask, request
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os
from os.path import join, dirname
import requests
import json
import telebot

def get_from_env(key):
    dotenv_path = join(dirname(__file__), '.env')
    load_dotenv(dotenv_path)
    return os.environ.get(key)

bot = telebot.TeleBot("***")

app = Flask(__name__)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['help', 'start'])
def send_welcome(message):
    bot.reply_to(message,
                 ("Hi there, I am EchoBot.\n"
                  "I am here to echo your kind words back to you."))

@app.route("/", methods = ["POST"])
def index():
    return {"ok": True}





if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Пишу сообщение `/start`, но бот не отвечает.

```
* Serving Flask app 'app.py' (lazy loading)
 * Environment: development
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Jun/2021 12:13:33] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Jun/2021 12:13:34] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А как Telegram должен понять, что Ваш сервер это адрес Вашего вебхука? Используйте метод [setWebhook](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api/#setwebhook) из официальной документации Telegram.

Вам нужно указать адрес Вашего сервера (например, https://example.com), все обновления будут стучаться туда.